# Minimum no. of grouping variables in mixed models

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

I have data where I collected `y` and predictors `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4` over multiple years at county-level. county is nested within 'State' and 'State' is nested within 'Province'

My model is

```
lmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (year|Province/State))
```

Is there a rule of thumb that says how many `State` should be present under `Province` for using lmer? For e.g. no. of `State` within a `Province` looks like this:

```
provinceID      stateCount
1                  1
2                  1  
3                  2
4                  3   
5                  5     
6                  6
7                  8
8                  9     
9                  11
10                 16  
11                 17
12                 20  
13                 30
14                 37
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My model is
>
> ```
> lmer(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (year|State/Province))
> ```

If `State` is nested within `Province` then you have specified the nesting the wrong way around. The correct formulation for the random effects is:

```
(year|Province/State)
```

which expands to

```
(year|Province) + (year|Province:State)
```

As for the number of states per province, I think you should be fine, however, in the case of province ID's 1 and 2, you might consider combining them into a single province.

Doug Bates, the original primary author of `lme4` fits nested models with 2 lower units per upper unit, in the `Pastes` dataset [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/www/lMMwR/lrgprt.pdf) (subsection 2.1.3.1).

To directly answer the question in the OP: I don't believe there is a rule of thumb, but if there is, then following blindly would be very unwise. This issue isn't really a problem because when fitting nested random effects, the software will estimate a variance for the interaction between the lower and upper level factors (as you can see from the expansion of `State/Province`) so provided that the total number of these is sufficient, which in your case it clearly is, there should not be a problem.